# To prove equality/inequality of plaintexts of 2 ciphertexts encypted under different encryption schemes

Tags: encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs, homomorphic-encryption, elgamal-encryption, paillier

We have 2 ciphertexts, one encrypted using Paillier and another encrypted under Elgamal encryption schemes. Is there a way to design ZK-proof to prove equality of the underlying plaintexts of these 2 ciphertexts.

Comment: I'd say this is quite straightforward via generic proof systems if the encryption protocols can be easily represented as arithmetic circuits over the same field, which is not the case here.